# How to display a fixed number of digits in C++ without rounding

Tags: c++, output, decimal-point

I have this code (very basic):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
float   a = 0.0,
        b = 0.0,
        c = 0.0;

cout<<"Input a: ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"input b: ";
cin>>b;
cout<<endl;
c = a / b;

cout<<"Result: "<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<c<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

When I enter two numbers (say, a = 513 and b = 791) I get 0.65. Calculator shows that the correct answer is 0.648. I understand that my code rounds up the last decimal number but this is not what  I want.

How can I get it to where it just stays as 0.64 and not 0.65?

Comment: You should check if `cin >> a` returns `true`. Otherwise the input has failed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you would like to truncate the value to two decimal places, you can multiply it by 100, truncate to integer, and then divide by 100, like this:

```
c = a / b;
c = floor(100 * c) / 100;
cout<<"Result: "<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<c<<endl;
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/FE4Wyv)

Comment: which library has trunc cause I have cmath in vs 2012 and its not taking it

Comment: @user2529011 It's `<cmath>` (see the demo, I added an `#include` for it).

Comment: I did and it still doesnt take it

Comment: error C3861: 'trunc': identifier not found

I'm using VS2012 BTW

Comment: @user2529011 Ah, I see, `std::trunc` was added in C++11, and VS 2012 is not C++11. You need to replace it with `floor` (edited, and changed the demo).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `trunc` to truncate to a certain number of digits:

```
c = a / b;

// truncate past two decimals:
c = trunc(c * 100) / 100;

cout<<"Result: "<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<c<<endl;
```

of for a generic function:

```
int trunc(double val, int digits)
{
    double pow10 = pow(10,digits);
    return trunc(val * pow10) / pow10;
}
```

then use

```
cout << "Result: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << trunc(c,2) << endl;
```

Comment: which library has trunc cause I have cmath in vs 2012 and its not taking it

Comment: Or you can cast `double` to `int` without using `trunc` method.