# Decimal Points rounding

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double a,b,result;
  a = 2;b = 3;
  result = a / b;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << result;

}
```

the output of this code in my IDE is :

```
0.67
```

i want the output to be

```
0.66
```

what do i do to change it to that

Comment: What you want is not rounding, but *truncating*.

Comment: `a=66;b=100;` will do the trick.

Comment: this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759131/how-to-display-a-fixed-number-of-digits-in-c-without-rounding

Answer (score 2):

Since you want truncation while `setprecision` uses rounding, you need to truncate the result manually:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << trunc(100*result)/100;
```

Multiplying and dividing by 100 keeps two decimal digits in place.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/k1b1Py)

**Note 1:** You have to be careful not to pass numbers that are close to the top of `double`'s range to avoid overflowing on multiplication.

**Note 2:** You can generalize this approach by multiplying and dividing by `pow(10,n)` where `n` is the number of decimal digits that you wish to keep.

Answer (score 1):

2 / 3 is 0.666666666..., which is indeed closer to 0.67 than to 0.66. So if you want to the latter, you have to actually change the result. You can do this using a simple function:

```
double truncate(double val, int precision)
{
  double shift = std::pow(10.0, precision);
  return std::trunc(val * shift) / shift;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try truncating with following:

```
result = (int)( 100 * a / b ) / 100.0;
```